# Row wise operations in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a way to perform row wise operations on matrices in octave ?

I have a `(mXn)` matrix of integers, can i obtain a `m dimensional` vector where each element is the maximum element of the corresponding row ? How can i do this in octave ?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'r' and 'matlab' when it seems to be an octave-specific question ?

Comment: In Matlab, this would be something like: `arrayfun(@(row)max(A(row, :), 1:size(A, 1))`

Comment: Its not tagged R any more. Octave is sufficiently matlabish that answers for one may be relevant to the other. Its not very R-ish though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In matlab, for a 2D array `A`, this would be

```
max(A,[],2)
```

and if you want to know the index of found the value:

```
[value,index]=max(A,[],2)
```

Comment: But but what's the empty matrix for?? The Matlab solution suggested in the comments above makes sense. help max did not help.